# Onclick not working with outside .JS file

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

what am I doing wrong here? I got a separate js file from my html but onclick doesn't seem to reach the js file I have. It works though if I place the function code inside the html. Help me.

//jlhtml.html

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="en">
 <head>
 <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text\javascript" src="jljs.js"></script>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 </head>
 <body>
 <center>
 <fieldset>
 <p>
 Search here: <input type="text" id="txtsearch"/> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp 
 <button onclick="Search()">Find now</button>
 </p>
 </fieldset>
 </center>
 </body>
 </html>
```

//jljs.js file below

```
 function Search()
 {
  var me = (d3.select("#txtsearch").property("value"));
  alert(me);
 }
```

Comment: You could always bind the click event using d3 instead of in the html tag.

Comment: How do I do that sir?

Comment: and can you point out what is wrong with my code? I want to understand why it is not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created a short snippet which binds the `Search` function to the button `click` event using d3.

```js
var searchButton = d3.select("#searchButton").on("click", Search);
 
 function Search() {
   var me = (d3.select("#txtsearch").property("value"));
   alert(me);
 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

  <body>
    <center>
      <fieldset>
        <p>
          Search here: <input type="text" id="txtsearch" /> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp
          <button id="searchButton">Find now</button>
        </p>
      </fieldset>
    </center>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: hey man, i appreciate your answer but for some reason it still don't work on me. No error message. I followed your code as is. I can't figure out what is wrong.

Comment: Put your external `<script>` below the body, might have to wait for the DOM to load the element.

Comment: Is it like this?<script type="text\javascript" src="ceribo.js"></script>
 
  </body>

Comment: or do I need to specify the exact file loc? like this  <script type="text\javascript" src="C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\ceribo\ceriboj.js"></script> </body>

Comment: You need to specify the [relative](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_filepaths.asp) file location to the html file.

Comment: Sorry man I'm so dumb. I did it like this <script type="text\javascript" runat="server" id="myID" src="~/ceribo/ceriboj.js"></script> but didnt work. The complete path though is C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\ceribo

Comment: if your html page is in the same folder all you need is `<script src="ceriboj.js"></script>`

Comment: Look at this [bl.ocks](https://bl.ocks.org/pmkroeker/d24fd09554f60acf0bf6c9a563a7425f) example. The `html` file and `js` file are in the same directory.

Comment: It is now working. As it turned out i included an extra </script>. Thank you so much. :)